# Changing the state before navigating without errors in react-native

Tags: javascript, react-native, mobx

I am using react native navigation and continually pushing the same screen onto a stack navigator. When the screen loads up it uses information from the mobx-state-tree store to decide how to render. The information in the store that determines how to render the screen needs to be updated before pushing another copy on the stack so that new screen knows how to render when it loads up. The problem is that in the short period of time between updating the store and pushing a new copy onto the stack the current screen gets updated with information meant for the next copy and crashes before navigating. Is there anyway to avoid the current screen updating with information meant for the next? Maybe I could update the store somewhere else in the lifecycle or stop the current screen from observing the store momentarily?

```js
menuItemPressed = () => {
    this.props.saleDemoStore.pushPageStack(this.props.menuItem.pointerType, this.props.menuItem.navPointer)
    if (this.props.menuItem.pointerType == "Menu") {
      this.props.navigation.push("menu")
    } else if (this.props.menuItem.pointerType == "Form") {
      this.props.navigation.push("form")
    }
  }
```

In the code above you can see the store get updated for the next screen and then after that the navigation is supposed to happen. However after the first line in the function the app crashes because for a split second the screen updates with bad data when it observes the new data in the store.

Comment: Is salesDemoStore.pushPageStack a function of parents?

Comment: @hongdevelop well its a function in the mobx-state-tree store so it doesn't belong to anyone. All components using that store are observing just the same.